# Printing Marks error in Inkscape 0.92

Tags: inkscape

I know where to find the settings for printing marks (**Extensions > Render > Layout > Printing Marks**) but I keep getting an error and I'm uncertain if it's a problem with Inkscape or user error.  I'm fairly new to Inkscape, so it very easily could be me not knowing how to use it!

I have a 5x7 graphic that I want printing marks on.  I have it all grouped together, but do I select it and then go for print marks?

Does it matter that I have another graphic on the same file, just over a bit?  (I make several originals in one svg file and just export them differently). I see lots of info online about how to get printing marks, but it's just not working for me and I have a feeling there is something I'm missing!

The error I get is:

> "Inkscape has received additional data from the script executed.  The script did not return an error, but this may indicate the results will not be as expected."
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Program Files/Inkscape/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 64, in 
>       import traceback
>   ImportError: Bad magic number in C:\Program Files\Inkscape\python\Lib/traceback.pyc

[image: Printing Marks settings]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Heather. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate the problem. The extension seems to be working fine for me in Inkscape 0.92.3

Comment: Mine shows only blocks for bleed margin lines. Is it only my case?

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably happening with all extensions for you, and it is (most probably) due to the update from an earlier Inkscape version to the one you're currently using not going smooth.

The update instructions on the inkscape.org website's [download page for Windows](https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.3/windows/) tell you to do the following:

Uninstall Inkscape completely (without removing your user preferences), and make sure that all Inkscape files in the directory where the program was saved are gone completely. Then reinstall it.